# how is literal .class object created in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

As we know when a java class X is loaded by class loader, a literal object X.class will be created. How is this object (i.e. X.class) created? created by "new" operator? Is it created on JVM **heap** memory or **method area** memory?

I tried to understand literal object X.class and it's relationship to class loader, but got confused

Comment: Are you talking about the `.class` file or the `java.lang.Class` object?

Comment: I mean the java.lang.Class object

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about the `java.lang.Class` object, that is actually created in native code and *not* using the `new` operator.

### Let's check

If we take a look at the `ClassLoader` implementation, it uses the `defineClass` methods for creating `Class` instances which delegate that to [`defineClass1` and `defineClass2`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/90d795abf10bf8b8b53079c1afd19fee7b4cb6cf/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ClassLoader.java#L1123-L1128).
These methods are `native` and therefore implemented in native (non-Java) code.

#### The native code

This happens in [`ClassLoader.c`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/90d795abf10bf8b8b53079c1afd19fee7b4cb6cf/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/ClassLoader.c#L72-L151) which then redirects to `JVM_DefineClassWithSource` in `jvm.cpp` which then calls [`jvm_define_class_common`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/90d795abf10bf8b8b53079c1afd19fee7b4cb6cf/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp#L867-L906).
This refers to a [`make_local` function](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/90d795abf10bf8b8b53079c1afd19fee7b4cb6cf/src/hotspot/share/runtime/jniHandles.cpp#L58-L72) which in tern refers to [`JNIHandleBlock::allocate_handle`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/90d795abf10bf8b8b53079c1afd19fee7b4cb6cf/src/hotspot/share/runtime/jniHandles.cpp#L424-L487) which seems to be used for allocations **on the Java Heap**.

### there's a constructor

`java.lang.Class` actually [has a private constructor](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/90d795abf10bf8b8b53079c1afd19fee7b4cb6cf/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#L241-L251). However, that is not used and only exists to trick the JIT and prevent developers to create `Class` instances:

> This constructor is not used and prevents the default constructor being generated.

and

> ```
> // Initialize final field for classLoader.  The initialization value of non-null
> // prevents future JIT optimizations from assuming this final field is null.
> ```

Since the constructor is never used, it cannot be created using the `new` keyword.

### Conclusion

With Hotspot, the instance creation currently happens in native code. Even though it isn't using the `new` keyword, it is still allocated on the Java Heap.

However, this part is JVM specific and can be different in other JVMs (e.g. OpenJ9).

Answer (score 3):

> As we know when a java class `X` is loaded by class loader, a literal object `X.class` will be created.

That is roughly correct, but your terminology is incorrect.  What is created is a `Class` object not a (class) "literal object".  A literal is something in your Java source code.  It *denotes* an object at runtime, but it is not the object.

> How is this object (i.e. X.class) created?

The Java runtime creates it.  When the class loader loads the class, it loads and records various class-related information (descriptors, bytecode blocks, and so on) in *meta-space*.  A `Class` object is also created to act as the runtime representation for the class which is visible to programs.

The mechanisms for loading classes, representing their metadata and creating the `Class` object are all implementation specific.  You don't need to know the details ... and they *may* vary between different Java versions.

> Is it created by "new" operator?

If you are referring to the Java `new` keyword, then No.  The creation will (typically) be done in native code.

> Is it created on heap memory or not?

That is implementation specific, but for current implementations the answer is yes.  For example, in Java 17 the `java.lang.Class` object is a heap object that is a "java proxy" for a native code descriptor called a `Klass`.

But >you< don't need to know this kind of detail. Even JNA / JNI programmers do not need to know how a `jclass` is implemented.  The only people who need to know this are those who write and maintain the JVM codebase.  (And if you are simply asking out of curiosity, I strongly recommend that you do your own research; i.e. by reading the OpenJDK source code.)